# How to fix this Error: '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i try to parse a document from Firestore in my flutter app.

Firestoredocument:

[image]

I created two classes to parse this document.

Class Produkt:

```
class Produkt{
  String name;
  int anzahl;

  Produkt({
    this.name,
    this.anzahl,
  });

  factory Produkt.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
    return Produkt(
        name:parsedJson['Name'],
        anzahl:parsedJson['Anzahl']
    );
 }
}
```

Class ProduktList:

```
class ProduktList{
  final List<Produkt> produkte;

  ProduktList({
    this.produkte,
  });

  factory ProduktList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
    var list = parsedJson["Produkte"] as List;
    List<Produkt> produkte = list.map((i) => Produkt.fromJson(i)).toList();

    return ProduktList(
        produkte: produkte,
    );
  }
}
```

When i built this an Exception is thrown:

```
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

I think, that the error occurs here:

```
List<Produkt> produkte = list.map((i) => Produkt.fromJson(i)).toList();
```

U Guys have an Idea how i can fix this problem?
Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Map object that you are using for `parsedJson` is obviously not a `Map<String, dynamic>`.

Assuming that we are able to cast this object to `Map<String, dynamic>`, try:

```
List<Produkt> produkte = list.map((i) => Produkt.fromJson(i.cast<String, dynamic>())).toList();
```

or:

```
List<Produkt> produkte = list.map((i) => Produkt.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic>.from(i))).toList();
```

take a look at a similar question here:
[How to cast an `_InternalLinkedHashMap` created from json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51260829/how-to-cast-an-internallinkedhashmap-created-from-json)

If it does not help, please add the code of how do you use `ProduktList.fromJson`, so we have more information about the error.