# List<dynamic> is not a subtype of List<Option>

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Cloud Firebase database with a `questions` collection. Each `question` has a list of map `options`.
I'm using Flutter and have the following classes for `question` and `option`:

```
class Question {
  final String text;
  final List<Option> options; // I have tried changing this to List<dynamic> but it doesn't help
  final String reference;

  Question(this.text, this.options, this.reference);

  Question.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, {this.reference}) : 
    text = map['text'],
    options = map['options']; // here the error happens

  Question.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
     : this.fromMap(snapshot.data, reference: snapshot.documentID);
}
```

and `option`

```
class Option {
  final String text;
  final int votes;
  bool isSelected;

  Option(this.text, this.votes, this.isSelected);

  Option.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) : 
    text = map['text'],
    votes = map['votes'];
}
```

I really have no idea how I can fix this. This kind of error seems to be everywhere on the internet, though. Any help is appreciated.

**Update**

For your information: `options` is an array of map in Cloud Firestore.

I changed my code based on the two answers below to:

```
factory Question.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {

    var options = map['options'];
    var text = map['text'];
    var reference = map['documentID'];
    List<Option> optionsList = options.cast<Option>();

    return new Question(
      text = text,
      options = optionsList,
      reference = reference
    );
  }

  factory Question.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return Question.fromMap(snapshot.data);
  }
```

Still, I get this error: `type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Option' in type cast`

I have seen and tried so many answers and all seem to say the same. I just can't figure this out.

Screenshot of Cloud Firestore:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up following `@chipli onat` advice and mix it with `@harsh` answer and finally got it to work. This is how my code looks like now:

```
class Question {
  final String text;
  final String reference;
  final List<Map> options;

  Question(this.text, this.options, this.reference);

  factory Question.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, String reference) {

    var options = map['options'];
    var text = map['text'];
    List<Map> optionsList = options.cast<Map>();

    return new Question(
      text = text,
      options = optionsList,
      reference = reference
    );
  }

  factory Question.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return Question.fromMap(snapshot.data, snapshot.documentID);
  }
}
```

and

```
class Option {
  final String text;
  final int votes;
  bool isSelected;

  Option(this.text, this.votes, this.isSelected);

  Option.fromMap(Map<dynamic, dynamic> map) : // notice Map<dynamic, dynamic> here
    text = map['text'],
    votes = map['votes'];
}
```

I'm sure this answer could be improved, but to be honest I don't understand entirely why it has to be so difficult. I hope this answer helps you.

Answer (score 8):

I've met with this problem before, I solved with

this is my code you can convert it to yours:

```
UserModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : documentReference = snapshot.reference,
        username = snapshot['username'],
        firstName = snapshot['firstName'],
        lastName = snapshot['lastName'],
        picture = snapshot['picture'],
        routes = Map.from(snapshot['routes']),
        avgScore = snapshot['avgScore'];
}
```

what your field type on cloud_firestore ?

if its a `Map` try to use `Map.from()`

if it's a `List` try to use `List.from()`

and change your local field the same type.

Comment: `options` is an Array of Maps in Cloud Firestore.

Comment: You solution does not work for me, I get this error: `type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Option'`

Comment: I tried `List.from()`, btw, as that makes sense, but I get the above error. I know that this answer should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: Can you post picture of related document from cloud firestore ?

Comment: I posted a screenshot. This is what it looks like basically: `options: [{text: "some text", votes: 0}]`

Comment: Any ideas? I'm starting to get desperate. The thing is I can't really use another kind of structure, because this is the best for my use case.

Comment: I'm looking at but instead of creating list of Option objects : `List<Option> options;` you should creat list of Maps `List<Map> options;` and you should be able to get from firestore , then you should fill your **Option** objects from these List of Maps.

Comment: I finally got it to work using your last suggestion! Thanks!

Comment: If its usefull for you, Can you make the answer accepted&upvote ?_? @Loolooii

Answer (score 2):

After encountering similar issues this worked perfectly for me:

```
class Question {
  final String text;
  final List<Option> options = [];
  final String reference;

  Question(this.text, this.options, this.reference);

  Question.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, {this.reference}){
    text = map['text'];
    if (map['options'] != null) {
      map['options'].forEach((v) {
      options.add(new Option.fromMap(v));
    });
   }
  }

  Question.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
    : this.fromMap(snapshot.data, reference: snapshot.documentID);
}

class Option {
  final String text;
  final int votes;
  bool isSelected;

  Option(this.text, this.votes, this.isSelected);

  Option.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) : 
    text = map['text'],
    votes = map['votes'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is more readable than your suggested solution. I used it in my project.

```
var optionsMap = map['options'] as List;
List<Option> optionsList = optionsMap.map((o) => Option.fromMap(o.cast<String, dynamic>())).toList();
```

```
class Option {
  final String text;
  final int votes;
  bool isSelected;

  Option(this.text, this.votes, this.isSelected);

  Option.fromMap(Map<dynamic, dynamic> map) : // notice Map<dynamic, dynamic> here
    text = map['text'],
    votes = map['votes'];
}
```

Source:
[How to fix this Error: '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54167985/how-to-fix-this-error-internallinkedhashmapdynamic-dynamic-is-not-a-subty)

Answer (score 0):

#### We are requesting a List but we are getting a List because our application cannot identify the type yet.

To remove this error, we have to explicitly cast the dynamic value.
In place of

```
  Question.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, {this.reference}) : 
  text = map['text'],
  options = map['options'];
```

use

```
  factory Question.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, {this.reference}) {
   var optionsFromMap  = map['options'];

  //you can use both the steps to check which one will work perfectly for you
  // List<Option> optionsList = new List<Option>.from(optionsFromMap)
   List<Option> optionsList = optionsFromMap.cast<Option>();

  return new Question(
    text = map['text'],
    options = map['options']; 
  );
}
```

the above code is working perfectly when I want List value

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I cannot pass `{this.reference}` to the factory method. Also, what do I do now with `fromSnapshot`? I get: `Generative constructor can't redirect to a factory constructor`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
 Question.fromMap(Map<dynamic, dynamic> map, {this.reference}) : 
    text = map['text'],
    options = map['options'].map<Option>((option) {
          return Option.fromMap(option);
        }).toList();
```