# Flutter & Provider, "type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'User'"

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, provider

Flutter throws exception on runtime: "type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'User'" when retrieving data from Firestore with StreamProvider.
Type safety can be enforced on the data in 'User' with .cast() or List.from(), but it makes no difference to the assertion. Even defining the offending List as dynamic in 'User' does not change the error.

I have read up extensively on this, like this [Github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18979), [typesafe Dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/sound-dart), and [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54851001/listdynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of-listoption). None of these solutions help, so hopefully someone here can help me.

Minimal code sample

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: StreamProvider<User>.value(
          value: userData,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return MyHomePage(title: 'Demo Error');
          }
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final User userData = Provider.of<User>(context) ?? []; // This asserts at runtime

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              '$userData.name',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

User _getUserFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot){

  List<String> categoriesFromDb = (snapshot.data['categories'] as List).cast<String>(); // Cast does not work

  return User(uid: '8GX2aGVn0GTrwLMxSZgx6STdnnA3',
    name: snapshot.data['name'],
    email: snapshot.data['email'],
    phone: snapshot.data['phoneNumber'],
    categories: categoriesFromDb,
    surname: snapshot.data['surname'],
  );

}

Stream<User> get userData{
  return Firestore.instance.collection('users')
      .document('8GX2aGVn0GTrwLMxSZgx6STdnnA3')
      .snapshots().map<User>(_getUserFromSnapshot);
}


class User {

  final String uid;
  final String name;
  final String surname;
  final String phone;
  final String email;
  final List<String> categories;

  User({this.uid, this.name, this.surname, this.email, this.phone, this.categories})
      : super();

}
```

Steps to reproduce:

-> Retrieve an array of Strings from Firestore collection with StreamProvider.

-> Map Firestore data to custom type ('User' in my case).

-> Flutter asserts at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because initial stat there is no data, so it returns List but you are trying to assign it to User type because of that you are facing this error.

You can solve by checking runtimeType as Following.

```
final User userData = Provider.of<User>(context).runtimeType == User
        ? Provider.of<User>(context)
        : null;
```

Comment: This works, thank you! I guess the actual error information put me off course, but this makes sense.